# Golang can't upgrade connection to webSocket

Tags: go, http, websocket

Trying to make a live chat app using webSocket, when trying to upgrade connection to webSocket get this error:" ***websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header***

Code:

```
func chat(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    funcName := logger.GetFuncName()
    logger.InfoHttp(r.URL.Path, r.Method, funcName)
    token, err := auth.GetToken(r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
        return
    }
    userId, err := auth.ValidateToken(token)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Couldn't validate token", err, funcName)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
        return
    }
    user, err := userController.GetUserById(userId)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Couldn't get user by id(%v)", userId), err, funcName)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
        return
    }
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error("Upgrade failed", err, funcName)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    }
    Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", user)
    defer func() {
        conn.Close()
        delete(websocketConn, conn)
    }()

    websocketMutex.Lock()
    websocketConn[conn] = true
    websocketMutex.Unlock()

    for {
        mt, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil || mt == websocket.CloseMessage {
            logger.Error("Couldn't read message", err, funcName)
        }
        fmt.Println(message)

        for conection := range websocketConn {
        err = conection.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
        if err != nil {
            conection.Close()
            logger.Error("Couldn't write massage to connection", err, funcName)
            delete(websocketConn, conection)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
func chat(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
funcName := logger.GetFuncName()
token, err := auth.GetToken(r)
if err != nil {
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
    return
}
userId, err := auth.ValidateToken(token)
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("Couldn't validate token", err, funcName)
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
    return
}
user, err := userController.GetUserById(userId)
if err != nil {
    logger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Couldn't get user by id(%v)", userId), err, funcName)
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", 302)
    return
}
conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
if err != nil {
    logger.Error("Upgrade failed", err, funcName)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
}
Tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", user)
defer func() {
    conn.Close()
    delete(websocketConn, conn)
}()

websocketMutex.Lock()
websocketConn[conn] = true
websocketMutex.Unlock()

for {
    mt, message, err := conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil || mt == websocket.CloseMessage {
        logger.Error("Couldn't read message", err, funcName)
    }
    fmt.Println(message)

    for conection := range websocketConn {
        err = conection.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
        if err != nil {
            conection.Close()
            logger.Error("Couldn't write massage to connection", err, funcName)
            delete(websocketConn, conection)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
func StartServer() {
var err error
Tmpl, err = template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html")
if err != nil {
    funcName := logger.GetFuncName()
    logger.Error("Couldn't parse tamplate", err, funcName)
}
http.HandleFunc("/chat/", chat)
err = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
if err != nil {
    funcName := logger.GetFuncName()
    logger.Error("Couldn't start the server", err, funcName)
}
```

}

..............................................................................................................................................................................

And a front end, I used gpt to generate it, so don't know if it is correct:

```
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type your message here" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script>
    const websocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/chat');

    const chat = document.getElementById('chat');
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    const input = document.getElementById('message');

    websocket.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log('WebSocket connected');
    };

    websocket.onmessage = (event) => {
        const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        chat.innerHTML += `<p>${message.username}: ${message.text}</p>`;
    };

    form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const message = input.value;
        const username = 'Alice'; // Change this to the username of the logged-in user
        const data = JSON.stringify({ username, text: message });
        websocket.send(data);
        input.value = '';
    });
</script>
```